# How to Return complex datatypes from functions in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, return-value, function-pointers, return-type

How can we return complex datatypes such as pointer to a int array from a function?

Consider the (non-compiling) code below:

```
int (*) [50] fcreate() 
{
    int (*p) [50]= new int[60][50];
    return p;
}
```

Why won't it work?

```
Error:
Expected un-qualified id before '(' in :

int (*) [50] fcreate();
```

Comment: Save yourself some pain and wrap the array in a type, and make sure that type owns the memory properly (like a smart pointer), better yet, use a vector and provide an accessor that takes 2 indices (and/or 1 index).

Comment: The syntax is `int(*fcreate())[50] { //... }`. That is a function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to int[50].

Comment: First learn something about pointers and arrays

Comment: pointers are as much as dynamic as much dangerous. learn about them first

Comment: Sorry for being a begineer...thanks @ Deidei

Comment: You got three solid answers, your question has been edited to make it more readable and you even complain because of a single downvote? Jeez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
int (*fcreate()) [50] {
    int (*p) [50]= new int[60][50];
    return p;
}
```

Or you could use an intermediate alias:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
using raw_array = T[N];

raw_array<int, 50>* fcreate() {
  int (*p) [50]= new int[60][50];
  return p;
}
```

But you'd rather combine `std::vector` and `std::array` if you want a 2-D matrix with fixed size for the second dimension:

```
auto fcreate() {
    return std::vector<std::array<int, 50>>{};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to first express the function with modern syntax:

```
auto fcreate()
    -> int (*)[50]
{ return new int[60][50]; }

auto main()
    -> int
{
    int x = fcreate;    // This won't compile: diagnostic shows syntax for you.
}
```

Then when you compile this the diagnostic for the declaration of `x`, tells you the old style syntax for declaring that function:

```
foo.cpp:8:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int (* (*)())[50]' to 'int'
```

I.e. with old syntax you would define this function as

```
int (*(fcreate)())[50]
{
    return new int[60][50];
}
```

That said, it's generally a better idea to use `std::vector`.

Or a matrix class defined with a `std::vector` for the internal storage.

---

The old syntax declaration looks ugly and, while its amenable to analysis it's difficult to synhesize. It can be simplified by defining a name for the array item type. Like this:

```
using Array_item = int[50];

Array_item* fcreate()
{
    return new int[60][50];
}
```

Instead of `using` you can use C++03 `typedef`.

But with the modern more clear trailing return type syntax this workaround has less advantage.

Comment: @akappa yes it is, [look at the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function), it's called trailing return type syntax

Comment: @Borgleader: I know what a trailing return type syntax is but, at least in C++03, the only standard-conformant way of declaring the main function was `int main(int, char**)`. Has this been changed in C++11?

Comment: And besides, using it in the `main` function is just showing off.

Comment: @akappa: AFAIK Holy Standard doesn't require any particular syntactic form for any declaration. Weasel phrase because there might just be something in C++17, it's so unpredictable. `auto main() -> int` is one of the two explicitly allowed forms of `main`for a hosted implementation, in C++98 through C++14, except that in C++98 and C++03 the trailing return type syntax wasn't available to express it.

Comment: OK, just consulted the `C++11` standard and that's indeed a legal `main` definition.

Comment: (although I still think it's an abuse of the syntax ;) )